# Make a programmatic change to trix without triggering trix-change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I'm trying to programmatically make a change to trix using something like:

```
element.editor.insertHTML('&nbsp;')
```

This works without issue, but unfortunately this is already within a trix-change event. So the insertHTML triggers itself again, and we're stuck in a loop.

So the question is, is there any way to make a change to the editor without triggering trix-change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag to ignore the next `trix-change` event. Something like:

```js
let ignoreNextChange = false

element.addEventListener("trix-change", () => {
  if (ignoreNextChange) {
    ignoreNextChange = false
    return
  }
  if (/* Your logic for inserting a non-breaking space */) {
    ignoreNextChange = true
    element.editor.insertHTML("&nbsp;")
  }
})
```